# Does not find modules, but they are

Tags: java, swing, module-info, djnativeswing

[image]

Please tell me, sincerely I can’t understand why it doesn’t find the module

Compiling errors occur:

```
error: module not found: DJNativeSwing.SWT 
error: module not found:DJNativeSwing
```

I added them to **IntelliJ** like this: **File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> + -> Java ->** Chose the path to **DJNativeSwing.SWT.jar** and **DJNativeSwing.jar**

I registered them in *module-info.java*, they recognized them, I can use their API in the main code, but it swears when compiling...

Comment: Which version of maven-compiler-plugin are you using?
Are you sure this library have automatic modules?

Comment: @notAPPP maven-compiler-plugin 3.10.1 version. I'm not sure if this library has automatic modules. What to do in this case? How to connect?